# Módulo no encontrado cuando intento crear la distribución de una aplicación JavaFX con Gradle

Tags: java, javafx, gradle, intellij-idea

Estoy tratando de crear la distribución de una aplicación usando Gradle, pero cuando intento ejecutar el binario generado, aparece el error:

```
 Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
 java.lang.module.FindException: Module com.example.fxtest not found
```

He leído algunas preguntas similares en el sitio en inglés, y la única solución que dan es pasar a Maven, u otras usando Gradle, pero en mi caso nada funciona.

¿No es posible crear una distribución de mi aplicación que funcione usando Gradle?

Este es mi `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.11'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.24.1'
}

group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.8.2'
}


tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'com.example.fxtest'
    mainClass = 'com.example.fxtest.Main'
}

javafx {
    version = '17'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.controlsfx:controlsfx:11.1.1')

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}
java {
    modularity.inferModulePath.set(true)
}

distributions {
    main {
        distributionBaseName = 'my-app'
    }
}
```

Tengo también el siguiente archivo  `module-info.java` en la carpeta: `src/main/java`:

```
module com.example.fxtest {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    requires org.controlsfx.controls;

    opens com.example.fxtest to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.fxtest;
}
```

#### Entorno de desarrollo

- Estoy usando `IntelliJ IDEA CE` como IDE
- Mi dispositivo es un Mac OSX M1 (nuevo procesador de Apple). En una [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74091052/5587982) que abrí en el sitio en inglés, algunos usuarios me han dicho que les funciona sin problema en Mac OSX con procesador Intel.

Debo decir que si ejecuto `run` por ejemplo desde el entorno de desarrollo la App se abre y funciona correctamente, pero si intento abrir el archivo unix que se crea en la carpeta `distributions` del proyecto al ejecutar el comando `build`, obtengo el error mencionando al principio de la pregunta. Los `.jar` para las diferentes plataformas se crean, pero tampoco abren si intento abrirlos directamente.

#### Reproducir el problema

Por si alguien quiere reproducir el problema, puede crear un proyecto nuevo desde `File > New Project`, luego selecciona a la izquierda un proyecto del tipo `JavaFX`  y en la opción `Build system` marca `Gradle`.

Luego, desde la terminal hace un `gradle build` o un `gradlew build` según sea su gradle y luego podrá ver la carpeta `distributions` dentro de la carpeta del proyecto.

El archivo `build.gradle` deberá parecerse al que indico más arriba, cambiando el nombre del proyecto, de la clase Main, etc.

Comment: Me parece que el problema está en que no le agregaste al proyecto in descriptor de módulo (`module-info.java`) y no estoy seguro de que puedas crear la imagen de la JVM usando jlink con un módulo automático.

PD: Lo pasos para reproducir el problema son para IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: @E.Betanzos en el proyecto existe desde el principio un archivo `module-info.java`, acabo de agregar su contenido en la pregunta y otros detalles sobre el entorno de desarrollo. Estoy usando IntelliJ IDEA, lo decía en la redacción anterior, aunque no muy visible. Lo del módulo automático es algo que agregué posteriormente, en base a sugerencias en otras preguntas, pero que luego quité porque no ha funcionado. Pondré el `build.gradle` como está ahora.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar `gradle jlink` en vez de `gradle build`, ya que la tarea (espero que así se llame, no conozco Gradle) que crea la imagen de la JVM se llama jlink (de acuerdo al `build.gradle` que compartes).

Una vez que hagas esto se debe de haber creado el directorio `build/image`, el cual contiene la imagen de la JVM que incluye todos los módulos de tú aplización, incluyendo el módulo principal (el de la aplicación JavaFX en sí).

Para ejecutar la aplicación puedes usar el archivo `build/image/bin/app.bat` en Windows o `build/image/bin/app` en Linux. También puedes usar el siguiente commando: `build/image/bin/java.exe -m com.example.fxtest./com.example.fxtest.Main`.

Si quieres distribuir la aplicación solo debes compartir el contenido de la carpeta `build/image`.

Comment: Agradezco tu interés. Cuando ejecuto la tarea `jlink` me da el siguiente error: `Process 'command '/Users/yo/Downloads/zulu17.36.17-ca-fx-jdk17.0.4.1-macosx_aarch64/zulu-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink'' finished with non-zero exit value 1` En ese carpeta es donde se supone que está el JDK para JavaFX.

Comment: @A.Cedano no uses un JDK que ya incluya las libs de JavaFX puesto que la configuración del propio proyecto ya las incluye a través de las dependencias de Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Recientemente tuve el mismo problema, tanto con Gradle como con Maven. Al final, adopté la solución de crear el "fat JAR" desde IntelliJ en lugar de usar Gradle; porque `gradle jlink` generaba un JRE distribuíble con un montón de archivos, y uno de los requisitos era precisamente entregar un JAR ejecutable.

---

Lo primero fue crear una clase `Launcher` que llame al main "real" de la clase que extiende Application (generalmente se llama HelloApplication o algo similar). Esto es porque no puede ejecutarse un main que extienda de Application directamente, por algún motivo que desconozco.

```java
public class Launcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloApplication.main(args);
    }
}
```

Para eso, vas a "Project Structure" (por defecto, Control+Alt+Shift+S o el equivalente en MacOS, si no lo encuentras puedes dar doble Shift y buscar ahí Project Structure) -> Artifacts y añadir JAR -> From modules with dependencies. **Importante no seleccionar el de JavaFX.**

Una vez en el diálogo, dejas el módulo por defecto y en "Main Class" seleccionas la clase `Launcher` creada anteriormente. El "JAR files from libraries" queda en "extract to the target JAR" e Include tests queda desmarcado.

Una vez hecho esto, puedes construir tu JAR desde el menú superior en Build -> Build Artifacts y seleccionas el que acabas de crear. Lo encontrarás en `raizDelProyecto/out/artifacts/loquesea_jar/loquesea.jar`, y al hacer doble click o ejecutar con `java -jar loquesea.jar` debería funcionar sin problema.

---

### Posibles problemas

1. El proyecto no funciona en otras plataformas.

Esto es normal, ya que Gradle solo instala los paquetes de JavaFX para la plataforma en la que está. Probablemente hay formas de incluir las dependencias de los diferentes sistemas soportados (Windows, MacOS y Linux) desde Gradle, pero es más fácil compilar en cada sistema su respectivo JAR, o mediante máquinas virtuales o algún sistema de CI como GitHub Actions.

2. El proyecto no se ejecuta por problemas con el Manifest.

Esto ocurre ya que algunas dependencias (en mi caso era Log4J y `at.favre.lib.bcrypt`) dan problemas por la forma en que se descomprimen, ya que incluyen su propio archivo `META_INF/MANIFEST.mf` que sobreescribe al de la aplicación. No encontré la forma de hacer que el MANIFEST de tu aplicación se copie el último, así que lo solucioné eliminando o sustituyendo estas dependencias.

3. La aplicación falla en cierto punto

Es poco probable que ocurra esto si el JAR se construyó bien, pero se puede ver una traza de pila de los errores o los mensajes que emita la aplicación si se ejecuta el programa con `java -jar [archivo_jar]` y haciendo la acción problemática. Si estos errores no ocurren en desarrollo con `gradle run`, seguramente sea algún problema con el artifact, y crearlo de nuevo probablemente lo arregle.

Comment: Gracias por tu interés. He intentando lo que me dices, pero al hacer el `build` me da el siguiente error: *`HelloController.java:4:28
java: package javafx.scene.control does not exist`* es la línea `4` de `HelloController` en la que hay esto: `import javafx.scene.control.Label;`, es como si no cargara las clases de `javafx.scene.control`, en la línea `3` hay esto: `import javafx.fxml.FXML;` pero no da problemas en esa línea.

Comment: @A.Cedano vete a la pestaña de artifacts nuevamente, selecciona el creado anteriormente y revisa que haya una línea "Extracted javafx-controls-[version]". Si no la hay, prueba a crear nuevamente el JAR From module with dependencies, y en "Module" selecciona el que termine por .main (habrá un .main y un .test).

Comment: `Extracted javafx-controls-[version]` existe tres veces, con diferentes versiones: `controls-11.1.1` y `controls-17-mac-aarch64` y `controls-17`.